# Passing multiple data using AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, variables

Can I pass multiple data variables using AJAX?

Are there better ways of doing this? (Considering speed and sustainability)

I have coded using this way

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'php/add_data.php',
        data: { data1: data1, data2: data2,data3: data3,data4: data4,data5: data5,data6: data6,data7: data7,data8: data8 },
        success: function(data) {
            window.location.href = 'zzz.php';
        }
    });
```

Comment: Yes, that looks fine. Are you having a specific problem with that structure?

Comment: ajax is just an http request. there's nothing magical about it. if you do something with an html form, you can do it via ajax.

Comment: The one problem I see is the `window.location.href = ...` in the `success` function. Ajax is for when you don't want to redirect, so if you want to redirect to zzz.php you might as well just use a regular HTML form.

Comment: thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can send in form of array in place of multiple variables.
eg

```
args = { 'data1': data1, 'data2': data2};
$.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'php/add_data.php',
        data: args,
        success: function(data) {
            window.location.href = 'zzz.php';
        }
    });
```

As arguments can be in any number(enhancements in future). It will be good to send in form of array.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I pass multiple data variables using AJAX?

Yes you can. You're code looks like it totally would work, given dataX variables are not undefined.

> Are there better ways of doing this? (Considering speed and
>   sustainability)

Your sample code looks pretty standard, I would dare to say it doesn't get any better than that.